# How to use "\M-\C-" as an key sequence prefix when defining key bindings using Readline in Bash?

Tags: bash, debian, terminal, readline

If I put `"\M-\C-k": kill-whole-line` in my `~/.inputrc` file the result is `"\213": kill-whole-line` (displayed by `bind -p`).

However, if I change `\M-` to `\e` (`"\e\C-k": kill-whole-line`), the key binding works as expected.

How can I use `\M-\C-` ("meta-control") as a prefix, when defining key bindings using Readline in `bash`?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `\M-` because it's broken. Keep using `\e` for the Meta/Alt prefix.

Using `\M-` in readline bindings does not work reliably with terminal emulators which prepend an ESC (`\x1b`) character instead of turning on the high bit when Meta/Alt is pressed and/or with UTF-8 locales (both of which are generally the default on most modern systems [1]).

With some versions of bash (e.g. `5.0`, but **not** the newer `5.1`), using `\C-\M-` works differently from `\M-\C-`, so just using `\C-\M-k` instead of `\M-\C-k` may actually do what you want -- until the next update ;-)

```
bash-5.0$ bind '"\C-\M-k": shell-backward-kill-word'
bash-5.0$ bind '"\M-\C-k": shell-kill-word'
bash-5.0$ bind -p | grep -a shell-.*kill-word
"\e\C-k": shell-backward-kill-word
"\213": shell-kill-word
```

[1]: not with `xterm` though, where you would need something like `XTerm*VT100.metaSendsEscape: true` in your `~/.Xresources`.

Comment: thank you. By "broken" you mean Readline is "bugged", or do you mean that I'm attempting something that's not right?

Comment: It's readline which is broken. Or at least its documentation -- they should clearly document that `\M-` is only usable with terminal emulators which are configured to use legacy 8-bit (non utf-8) encodings *and* to turn the high bit instead of prepending an ESC when Alt is pressed. But there are zero reasons to use that config nowadays, and it's not the default anywhere.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. Lots of frustration over here too :)